Encounter "Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for .." error when upgrade ABP from 5.x to 8.x
Following error was throw when I upgraded the Volo.Abp.AutoMapper package via Manage NuGet Packages.
"unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight'........."
I had tried to upade the dependent components. but unfortunately, it still prompts many of the similar error ...

Hi, did you try to uninstall Volo.Abp.AutoMapper package and install 8.x version directly via Manage Nuget Packages?


"unable to satisfy conflicting requests for 'System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight'........."

From looking at the error message, it seems a NuGet Error NU1106,it notes a solution

Edit the project file to specify more open-ended ranges for the dependency rather than an exact version.

Please try to  add the following into your .csproj file
<PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight" Version="4.3" />

Based on my test, the Volo.Abp.AutoMapper package dependents on System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.It seems that Volo.Abp.AutoMapper has specific version constraints, and the version you are trying to upgrade might be conflicting with other installed packages.

Plese try to uninstall the Volo.Abp.AutoMapper package and reinstall  the version 8.x via Nuget Package Manger.
Docs  Referred:
Version ranges
